# Application has stopped when launching the app with splash screen

Tags: java, android

I created a splash screen in my application suddenly when I ran the code it stopped. I created a splash screen in my code then it will redirect you to the menu. Is there something wrong with the android manifest xml?

Here's my manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kenneth.rusa">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.action.LAUNCHER">
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".Play">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the splash class code:

```
package com.example.kenneth.rusa;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.SystemClock;


/**
 * Created by Kenneth on 8/6/2016.
 */
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity   {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcomeactivity);
    RunMe runme = new RunMe();
    Thread t = new Thread(runme);
    t.start();

}
class RunMe implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        SystemClock.sleep(3000);
        Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: could you please post the logcat too..

Comment: Why do you need 3 Activities added to your home screen launcher?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove following lines from activities other than splash

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: It's not necessary but recommended, I've tested having multiple activities with these filters and the first one takes the priority and is the `LAUNCHER`.

Comment: Your launcher is WelcomeActivity but it is not defined at first place in your code shared here. Please follow the recommended. Atleast give it a try and check your problem.

Comment: It's not my code :)
I just said that I've tried this and is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I fixed it by changing the manifest file

Here's the updated code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kenneth.rusa">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".Play">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.default"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```